# Query to use a CASE WHEN nested AND and OR functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select      imitmloclotq.item_code as "Item Code",
            imitmloclotq.lot_no as "Lot #",
            format(imitmloclotq.qty_on_hand, 'n2') as "Qty On Hand",
            imitmloclotq.sub_inv_code as "Location",
            imitmloclotq.locator_code as "Sub Location"

from        imitmloclotq (nolock)

where       qty_on_hand !=0

order by    item_code, lot_no
```

And it spits out a large amount of data like this below:

```
Item Code           Lot #   Qty On Hand Location    Sub Location
-----------------------------------------------------------------
30501302            2177        5.00    F1          7C          
30501305            1512        4.50    F1          5E          
30501305            1512        -0.67   F1          FLOOR       
30501306            1513        14.50   F1          5E          
30501310            2229        31.81   F1          2A          
30501312            1919        5.00    F1          4B
```

But what I want is to add a column which is called "Multiple Locations" which would display "Multiple" if the row was the same item as the row above, but either the Location or the Sub Location was different. For example item 30501305 above has two lots in two different Sub Locations (5E and FLOOR). Another item might have the same Sub Location but the Location could be different.

I need some code that would say something like this but I really don't know:

```
CASE 
   WHEN (imitmloclotq.item_code = previous row imitmloclotq.item_code) 
        AND (OR(imitmloclotq.sub_inv_code != previous row imitmloclotq.sub_inv_code, imitmloclotq.locator_code != previous row imitmloclotq.locator_code)) 
      THEN "Multiple" 
      ELSE "" 
END
```

Comment: Should it display `Multiple` on both rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you want `lag()`:

```
select i.item_code as "Item Code",
       i.lot_no as "Lot #",
       format(i.qty_on_hand, 'n2') as "Qty On Hand",
       i.sub_inv_code as "Location",
       i.locator_code as "Sub Location"
       (case when lag(i.sub_inv_code) over (partition by item_code order by lot_no) <> i.sub_inv_code or
                  lag(i.locator_code) over (partition by item_code order by lot_no) <> i.locator_code
             then 'Multiple'
         end) as new_column                  
from imitmloclotq i
where qty_on_hand <> 0
order by item_code, lot_no;
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! I cleaned it up and it is working perfectly. Thanks again

Comment: PS, now you pointed me inthe right direction I found this very useful link, cheers.

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lag-function/